# Python package works on the command line but cannot be found in a script

Tags: command-line, python, python3, pip, executable

Basically from the title and the image below, I have installed `pyserial` and it works in the Python terminal but not in a script.

I have done `pip3 install pyserial`, and have also tried `pip install pyserial` and `python3 -m pip install pyserial`, which return that I already have the package installed.

When I use `python3`, enter the Python terminal, and enter `import serial` there are no errors. When I have a script using `import pyserial` and run it using `python3 ./serial_test.py`, it gives the error.

Why does one throw an error and the other not? And how may I fix this?

Here is a screenshot of my terminal:

[image: Image of my terminal]

My python script, no matter if the script uses the `serial` library, throws the error:

[image: python script]

**Edit 1:** One thing I forgot to mention was that when I do `pip3 --version` it shows:

```
pip 22.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

instead of:

```
/usr/lib/python3...
```

as [listed here](https://www.linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-18.04), although this still would not explain the difference in the in-terminal code.

Maybe a solution would be to install it using `pip` for `/usr/lib/python3`, however I am unsure how to do that.

**Edit 2:** As I look further into this, I will update my findings. When I do `whereis python3`, I get:

```
python3: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3.8-config /usr/lib/python3 /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.9 /etc/python3 /etc/python3.8 /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /usr/include/python3.8 /usr/share/python3 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz
```

I am unsure how programs work on the command line, so I am not sure why there are multiple places for `python3`, but maybe it will explain the issue.

**Edit 3:** `which python3` shows:

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

and `which pip3` shows:

```
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option A:**

You can try to run:

```
/usr/local/bin/pip3 install serial
```

and then:

```
/usr/bin/python3 serial_test.py
```

and check if you still face the same problem. If you do, then try Option B.

**Option B:**

You can try to create a virtual environment via:

```
virtualenv -p python3 venv
```

or:

```
python3-venv
```

and try to execute the program.

**NOTE**

You are using Python 3 as your user in normal mode, while you are using root when launching the script, as shown in the image you uploaded.
Using Python 3 as `sudo` will launch `python` as the root user and maybe the `$PATH` will not be the same for `python` and `pip`.

You might have installed the `serial` module in your user's `pip` path, but it may not be present in root user's `pip` path and that's why you are facing the issue!

Comment: Okay it was definitely your last point that it was because I was running it as sudo, running "sudo python3" and then importing the library throws the error as well. You definitely got me on the right track to fixing the issue so thanks! Do you know how I could either install the library for sudo or give python or my user more permissions? (not sure how it works)

Comment: It was pleasure helping you :)  Sure you can use ```sudo python3``` and ```sudo pip3 install <xyz>``` to install modules for root. But I won't recommend it.